# Simple Hotel Booking Form Total Calculation

Tags: javascript, forms

I wonder if anyone can help me... Unfortunately I do not have any Javascript knowledge and finding it a bit difficult to understand.

I am working on a Hotel Booking form and this is what I need to do. There is an option to choose the hotel as well as the options for how many nights are required.

There is also a Totals field. This is where I am stuck. Can someone help me with a script or what to do get the Total field to show the total of the formula of nights times choice of hotel?

This would also need to be a value that would be posted with the other values to the php form which in turn sends me the email with the values.

Here is the link to the form I made: https://www.alpinemalta.net/libyabuild2013/bookNow.html

Thank you to anyone that can help me and please excuse my lack of knowledge in this area.

Regards

Chris Brown (Malta)

Comment: How much cost for 1 night ?

Comment: Could you post the code you have tried so far here?

Comment: I didnt know Chris Brown codes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at your form,

1) i think the drop down list for total of nights is redundant (the total of nights is clear from arrival and departure dates)

2) the dates (for having it simpler using it in JavaScript) use numeric values instead of: '11/05/2013(A)' or such.

```
<select name="ArrivalDate" size="1" id="ArrivalDate">
<option>Please select</option>
<option value="1368399600">13-05-2013</option>
<option value="1368486000">14-05-2013</option>
...
</select>
```

3) i didn't notice anywhere the price per night? Maybe the list of hotels could also contain some ID (such as h1a,h1b, h2a, h3a, h3b, h3c, ...) instead of the textual option description (of hotel and room)

```
<select name="hotel_choice" id="hotel5">
<option value="nothing" selected="selected">None Selected</option>
<option value='nothing'>.</option>
<option value="h1a">Corinthia Single Room</option>
<option value="h1b">Corinthia Double Room</option>
<option value='nothing'>.</option>
...
</select>
```

if you do that then the JavaScript may not be that complicated (asuming you do those changes and don't mind having the price for each hotel visible in the page source):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var prices={nothing:0,h1a:357,h1b:280.50,h2a:380}; //here are your hotel prices

function calculate() {
    var days = Math.round( ( 
            document.getElementById('datedepart').value - 
            document.getElementById('ArrivalDate').value 
        ) / 86400 ); //timestamp is in seconds
    document.getElementById('total_cost').value = 
        days * 
        prices[ document.getElementById('hotel5').value ];
}
</script>
```

please note that there aren't any niceties in the code and it's based on the assumption, that the dates are changed to their representative integer values (such as are returned by php function time() ) also it is possible that i made an error in the ID names of your elements

Then what remains is to hook up the "calculate();" javascript function to **onchange** event of all the controls and you are done.

```
<select name="hotel_choice" id="hotel5"  onchange='calculate();'>
...
</select>
```

and

```
<select name="ArrivalDate" size="1" id="ArrivalDate" onchange='calculate();'>
...
</select>
```

and the same in the departure date selector.

EDIT:

You could use dates in your date selectors, but you would have to parste that string into a number client side using something like:

```
var dt=Date.parse(document.getElementById('ArrivalDate').value);
```

But make sure to check supported date formats for this function and also note it returns the number of **milliseconds** since 1970 so you will have to be dividing by 86400000 instead of 86400

**EDIT - check for dates are filled in**

```
function calculate() {
var dd=document.getElementById('datedepart');
var da=document.getElementById('ArrivalDate');
var total=document.getElementById('total_cost');
var hotel=document.getElementById('hotel5');

//no hotel room selected or not depart date set or not arrival date set
//or departing before arrival (nonsense) - set total to ZERO and exit the function

if ( !(dd.value*1) || !(da.value*1) || da.value>dd.value ) {
    total.value='0';//you can set it to 'not allowed' also if you wish (instead of '0')
    return;
}

var days = Math.round( ( 
        dd.value - 
        da.value 
    ) / 86400 ); //timestamp is in seconds
var cost = days * prices[ hotel.value ];
if (isNaN(cost))
    cost = 0; //or set to "invalid input" - but this line should not be needed at this point
total.value = cost;
}
```

Comment: @ChrisBrown try to add into the `function calculate()` this line: `alert("value: '"+dd.value+"' ; !value:'"+(!dd.value)+"' ; (value*1): '"+(dd.value*1)+"' ; !(value*1): '"+(!(dd.value*1))+"' ; !NaN: '"+(!NaN)+"'");` Then reload the page (or better re-open it) and just change the hotel selector and you should see something like: `value: 'Please select' ; !value:'false' ; (value*1): 'NaN' ; !(value*1): 'true' ; !NaN: 'true'` the value is what's stored in dd.value. First i was testing !dd.value, which evaluates FALSE because there IS something in it. so i changed it to `!(dd.value*1)`

Comment: @ChrisBrown because `dd.value*1` evaluates to "NaN" (simply because "Please select"*1 is nonsense, you can not multiply a word and a number... :) and then i am checking whether `!NaN` is true. Luckily NaN on it's own in boolean expressions seems to evaluate as FALSE (similarly as 0 (zero) would) and that solves the problem.